# "show 1 more comment" link on LQP review audit, clicking gives "An error occurred while fetching comments"

Tags: bug, comments, review, review-audits, low-quality-posts

On [this LQP review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12481730), I see a "show **1** more comment" link.

[image]

When I click it, I get an error message: "An error occurred while fetching comments".

[image]

Possibly related: [Zombie comments (aka wrong comments count when destroying a spammer who posted comments)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281951/zombie-comments-aka-wrong-comments-count-when-destroying-a-spammer-who-posted-c)

Comment: Just FYI, [that's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vTIIMJ9tUc8) what that deleted post is about.

Comment: For a second I thought [Tunaki](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1743880/tunaki) had a fan.