# Zombie comments (aka wrong comments count when destroying a spammer who posted comments)

Tags: bug, comments, deleted-accounts, account-destruction

I noticed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281895) (10k only) that there is "show 2 more comments":

> [image]

Clicking it has no effect.  Viewing the raw server response, it simply returns the existing comments.

This is most likely the result of [destroying the account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276378/152859), which somehow fails to update the comments count on the spammer's posts, in case they wrote comments. (And yes, I am sure those two comments have been written by that user, as I've seen them before the account was deleted.)

Can this please be fixed?

Not sure if it matters, but as can be seen in the screenshot, the question was deleted before the account has been destroyed.

Comment: FWIW: I've seen this happen a couple times before for no apparent reason. The count is apparently cached and sometimes gets out of sync.

Comment: @Alexander well, I gave the reason, and pretty sure I'm not wrong. And it's not caching, it's a static field in database table, which isn't updated correctly.

Comment: I didn't say it was wrong, just that the issue is likely greater than this one case.